# making a default filename rather than *.xps on .print() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to change the filename of my printing document so instead of having it with *.xps i wanted to change it with something else, is there any way to do it? [image: Default filename]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

On most typically configured systems, `window.print()` will prompt the user to send the web page to an actual printer. You're only seeing the XPS interface because you don't have a printer configured, or because you have the XPS writer set as your default printer for some reason.

Comment: so if i have a printer there is no need for a filename isnt it?